# How to share/split a Redux Store between multiple generic components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, state

I have a generic component called "VendorResults". I am passing a string prop down to each of these generic components such as "Microsoft", "Apple", etc.

```
    <ScrollView>
     <SearchResults/>
     <VendorResults vendor={"microsoft"}/>
     <VendorResults vendor={"oracle"}/>
    </ScrollView>
```

Within this generic component, I am passing the vendor prop as a parameter to my Redux-Thunk actions as such:

```
  componentDidMount() {
     const {vendor} = this.props;
     this.props.getVendorInformation(vendor);
  }
```

An API call kicks off, and Thunk actions are dispatched. The data eventually makes its way to the Reducer and store. However, When I have more than one generic Vendor component, whichever async call finishes last, appears to take precedent over all the others. For example, if oracle finishes loading last, the microsoft component's state will change and show oracle data.

**Actions**

```
  export function getVendorInformation(vendor) {

  const url = `${VENDOR_URL}api/search/${vendor}`;

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getVendor());
    fetch(url)
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(getVendorSuccess(data))
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        dispatch(getVendorError(e.message))
      });
  };
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function(state=initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCHING_VENDOR: return {payload:[], fetching: true}
        case FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS: return {payload: action.payload.data}
        case VENDOR_ERROR: return {payload:[], error: true, ...state}
    }
    return state;
}
```

**My Question:**

I want to maintain this pattern of generic/reusable Vendor components - I do not want a new component for each vendor. The same goes for actions/reducers; unique vendor actions/reducers would get messy.

How can I share/split/partition a single Redux store into vendor specific chunks to maintain seperation of state but still benefit from one flow. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass vendor to reducer via action and re-do structure of your state. If list of vendors is pre-determined and not very long, it probably will be less messy to just create separate actions/reducers.

Otherwise, you need to have nested reducer:

```
const supportedActions = [FETCHING_VENDOR, FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS, VENDOR_ERROR];

const initialVendorState = {data:[], fetching: false, error: false};

const vendorReducer = (state = initialVendorState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCHING_VENDOR: return {data:[], fetching: true}
        case FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS: return {data: action.payload.data}
        case VENDOR_ERROR: return {...state, data:[], error: true}
    }
    return state;
}

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (supportedActions.includes(action.type)) {
    const s = {};
    s[action.payload.vendor] = vendorReducer(state[action.payload.vendor], action);
    return {
      ...state,
      ...s
    };
  }

  return state
}

export default reducer;
```

And your action creators should take `vendor` as parameter and pass it to reducer:

```
const fetchVendorSuccess = (vendor, data) => ({
  type: FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    vendor,
    data
  }
});
```

In your `connect` function you will need to use smth like `data: (state[vendor] || {}).data` to avoid errors if state does not have any info about that vendor

Answer (score 0):

> However, When I have more than one generic Vendor component, whichever async call finishes last, appears to take precedent over all the others. For example, if oracle finishes loading last, the microsoft component's state will change and show oracle data.

You are seeing Oracle data because after fetching the vendor data you are overwriting the entire vendor state with the latest array of vendor items.

```
  case FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS: return {payload: action.payload.data}
```

To avoid this, you would need to merge the previous state with the new state.

Solution depends on what each vendor response looks like. As Gennady suggested, you can use an object and make each vendor a property on the object.

Using a flat array to store all the different vendor items presents challenges. How would you determine if a vendor has already been fetched?

To avoid overwriting the previous vendor, you would need to merge the new state with previous state. E.g.

```
  case FETCH_VENDOR_SUCCESS: return [...state.data, ...payload.data]
```